# Integrating total differential, thermodynamics

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

In my textbook of physical chemistry I encountered strange derivation:
by integrating

$$dU=TdS-pdV+\sum_{i=0}^n \mu_i dn_i $$
we get
$$U=TS-pV+\sum_{i=0}^n \mu_i n_i . $$
I tried to understand this. dU is total differential, that means that I should solve it like path integral, and I can chose any path. I know that from these it possible to show that integral of total differential is sum of definite integrals. I am not sure what start and end points I should chose. I assume that there are some hidden assumptions in text, that should be self-evident.
$$U=\int_0^S T(S,V,A, n_1, n_2...)dS-\int_0^p p(S,V,A, n_1, n_2...)dV+ \int_0^\mu \mu_i(S,V,A, n_1, n_2...) dn_i +C.$$
Please show step by step solution and book where its written, preferably older book.

Comment: There's not much to explain here. This follows from the so-called fundamental theorem of calculus -- integrating the differential of a quantity gives back the quantity. Intuitively, summing of infinitesimal differences in the values of a function over some interval gives you back the function. The only other thing used here is the distributivity of the integrating operator.

Comment: I invested very much time to understand it. I don`t understand it now. Can you show me step by step solution. It doesn`t look like something self-evident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is the following. We assume that $U(S,V,n)$ is a homogeneous function of order 1 that is $U(\lambda S, \lambda V, \lambda n)=\lambda U(S,V,n)$ (physically it means that if we increas the system $\lambda$ times then the energy increase $\lambda$ times, in other words $U$ is extensive). Then we can use Euler's Homogeneous Function Theorem (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html) so we get
\begin{equation}
U(S,V,n ) =\Big(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\Big) S +\Big(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\Big) V+ \Big(\frac{\partial U}{\partial n}\Big) n
\end{equation}
Where we know the partial derivatives from the equation $dU=TdS-pdV+\mu n$  (for example $\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}=T $  and so on..) Finally we get
\begin{equation}
U(S,V,n ) =T S -pV+\mu n
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a more general way to integrate this total differential, without using homogeneous function properties? Why is there no integration constant? What would be integration result if U wasn't a homogeneous function.

Comment: This is the standard way to do, you can also chech here ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_equations#Euler_integrals ). As I see the homogeneous property is neceserry, you can't conclude this result without it. In physics the change of energy is important, that's why the constant doesn't matter. Unfortunately I don't know good thermodynamics book, but you can looking for here:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394714/thermodynamics-books-recommendations
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5614/references-about-rigorous-thermodynamics